# Cómo obtener la response adecuada de una API Node desde una App en Flutter?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, api, flutter, postman

En la App SMApp en Flutter, desde el archivo horarios_service.dart:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'horarioform.dart';

class HorariosService {
  final http.Client _http;

  HorariosService(this._http);

  Future<List<HorarioDetailsModel>> obtenerHorarios(
      String? estacionSeleccionada, String? hora) async {
    if (estacionSeleccionada == null || hora == null) {
      throw Exception('Error: estación y hora son requeridos');
    }

    try {
      print('Datos Enviados a la API');
      print(
          'Estacion seleccionada: $estacionSeleccionada, Hora seleccionada: $hora');
      final response = await _http.get(Uri.parse(
          'http://localhost:2500/horarios/$estacionSeleccionada/$hora'));
      print('Datos Recibidos de la API');
      print(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonHorarios = json.decode(response.body)['horarios'];
        final horarios = jsonHorarios.map<HorarioDetailsModel>((jsonHorario) {
          print('Horario procesado: $jsonHorario');
          return HorarioDetailsModel(
            numTren: jsonHorario['num_tren'].toString(),
            horaEstacion: jsonHorario['hora_estacion'].toString(),
          );
        }).toList();
        print('Horarios obtenidos:');
        horarios.forEach((horario) {
          print(
              'Número de Tren: ${horario.numTren}, Hora en la estación: ${horario.horaEstacion}');
        });
        return horarios;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Error al obtener los horarios: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Error en la solicitud a la API: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

estoy enviando los datos desde un formulario a la API Node:

```
// Ruta para obtener los horarios de la estación y hora especificadas
app.get("/horarios/:estacion/:hora", (req, res) => {
  const { estacion, hora } = req.params;

  // Reemplazar espacios en el nombre de la estación con guiones bajos para que coincida con el nombre de la columna
  const columnEstacion = estacion.replace(/ /g, "_");

  // Consulta para obtener los horarios de la estación y hora especificadas
  const query = `
    (SELECT num_tren, ${columnEstacion} AS hora_estacion
    FROM horarioida
    WHERE ${columnEstacion} <= ? ORDER BY ${columnEstacion} DESC LIMIT 2)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT num_tren, ${columnEstacion} AS hora_estacion
    FROM horarioida
    WHERE ${columnEstacion} > ? ORDER BY ${columnEstacion} ASC LIMIT 2)
  `;

  connection.query(query, [hora, hora], (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error al obtener los horarios: " + err.stack);
      res.status(500).json({ mensaje: "Error al obtener los horarios" });
    } else {
      res.json({ horarios: results });
    }
  });
});
```

esperando la respuesta que me genera POSTMAN, GET, http://localhost:2500/horarios/Santos_Lugares/06:00:

```
{
    "horarios": [
        {
            "num_tren": "3317",
            "hora_estacion": "05:51"
        },
        {
            "num_tren": "3315",
            "hora_estacion": "05:35"
        },
        {
            "num_tren": "3319",
            "hora_estacion": "06:05"
        },
        {
            "num_tren": "3321",
            "hora_estacion": "06:21"
        }
    ]
}
```

Sin embargo la respuesta recibida es:
Datos Enviados a la API
Estacion seleccionada: Santos_Lugares, Hora seleccionada: 6:00 AM
Datos Recibidos de la API
{"horarios":[{"num_tren":"3331","hora_estacion":"07:42"},{"num_tren":"3329","hora_estacion":"07:23"}]}
Horario procesado: {num_tren: 3331, hora_estacion: 07:42}
Horario procesado: {num_tren: 3329, hora_estacion: 07:23}
Horarios obtenidos:
Número de Tren: 3331, Hora en la estación: 07:42
Número de Tren: 3329, Hora en la estación: 07:23
Selected station: Instance of 'Estacion'
Selected time: 6:00 AM
Horarios recibidos: [Instance of 'HorarioDetailsModel', Instance of 'HorarioDetailsModel']

Los valores obtenidos representan los dos ultimos registros de la columna Santos_Lugares en la Tabla horarioida de la BBDD sanmartinretiro:

Santos_Lugares * Valor Obtenido; ** Valor Correcto
01:57
null
04:05
null
04:37
04:54
05:05
05:21
05:35
05:51 **
null
06:05 **
06:21 **
06:37 **
06:51
07:08
07:23 *
null
07:42 *
null
null

Mi pregunta es:
Como debo configurar el Código en horario_service.dart para que me traiga los 4 horarios correctos, tal como lo hace con POSTMAN?

Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la respuesta del servicio esta bien solo que al pasar al modelo no queda bien , podria usar este modelo.

```
import 'dart:convert';

HorarioDetailsModel horarioDetailsModelFromJson(String str) => HorarioDetailsModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String horarioDetailsModelToJson(HorarioDetailsModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class HorarioDetailsModel {
    final List<Horario>? horarios;

    HorarioDetailsModel({
        this.horarios,
    });

    HorarioDetailsModel copyWith({
        List<Horario>? horarios,
    }) => 
        HorarioDetailsModel(
            horarios: horarios ?? this.horarios,
        );

    factory HorarioDetailsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HorarioDetailsModel(
        horarios: json["horarios"] == null ? [] : List<Horario>.from(json["horarios"]!.map((x) => Horario.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "horarios": horarios == null ? [] : List<dynamic>.from(horarios!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Horario {
    final String? numTren;
    final String? horaEstacion;

    Horario({
        this.numTren,
        this.horaEstacion,
    });

    Horario copyWith({
        String? numTren,
        String? horaEstacion,
    }) => 
        Horario(
            numTren: numTren ?? this.numTren,
            horaEstacion: horaEstacion ?? this.horaEstacion,
        );

    factory Horario.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Horario(
        numTren: json["num_tren"],
        horaEstacion: json["hora_estacion"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "num_tren": numTren,
        "hora_estacion": horaEstacion,
    };
}
```

- generado con https://app.quicktype.io/

y en la respuesta del servicio

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {

final horario = HorarioDetailsModel.fromJson(resonse.body);

print(horario.toJson());
}
```